# Getting all connected nodes in neo4j, using neo4j-driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have been developing a javascript wrapper library over neo4j-driver. Though I was facing a little difficulty to obtain all the nodes using the api.

The query does work in neo4j browser, but returns only a single node using neo4j-driver.

```
MATCH (n) MATCH (n)-[r]-(p) RETURN p
```

For instance:
[image: Using broweser]

Whereas using neo4j-driver:
[image]

My question:
Is there another way(another query) that could return me all the connected nodes?

Comment: all nodes connected to each other or high level database schema?

Comment: Simply a node(microController) is connected to 2 nodes of type(Switch) with relationship[:serves]

Comment: try `return *` .

Comment: Still doesn't return both switches.. Rather the controller and relationship is returned alon with switch2. I basically require returning both switches

Comment: it's strange because the browser also use the neo4j js driver, so you should have the same result. Do you have the same result than the browser if you use the CLI `cypher-shell` ?

Comment: Can you put your code up that is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the response you get from neo4j-driver library as the Cypher Query returns all nodes, as per the relation, i.e, MATCH (n) MATCH (n)-[r]-(p) RETURN p, returns all nodes connected to (n).

Check the way you are parsing the result from the neo4j-driver.